# How to append $metadata['sizes'] to metadata when using 'wp_generate_attachment_metadata?

Tags: post-meta, attachments

When a file such as an image is uploaded, an optimized version is created with `$saved = $editor->save($editor->generate_filename('name'));`. This successfully writes the file to disk and the intermediate sizes are created too from the source/original image.

I'd like to add the optimized version to the array of sizes. I've tried the following but no additional size is added to the metadata array.

```
$metadata['sizes']['full'] = [];
$metadata['sizes']['full']['file'] = $saved['file'];
$metadata['sizes']['full']['width'] = $saved['width'];
$metadata['sizes']['full']['height'] = $saved['height'];
$metadata['sizes']['full']['mime-type'] = $saved['mime-type'];
$metadata['sizes']['full']['filesize'] = $saved['filesize'];
```

I've attempted `$metadata['sizes'] = array('full' => $saved,);` but again the 'full' size isn't added/appended to the list existing array.

How can I go about adding/pushing/merging it?

Comment: Is your code run inside of an action or filter? Please provide more details.

Comment: @Caleb, it runs with `add_filter('wp_generate_attachment_metadata'`

Answer (score 0):

Although the [suggested answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/416916/65882) from `admcfajn` wasn't the solution to the problem/question, it did lead me to look explore it further. Thanks `admcfajn`.

Assuming you are using either the default intermediate e.g. `thumbnail` or custom sizes e.g. `320w` and would like to include additional sizes such as `full`, you can use `wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $metadata );`